# mongorestore does not restore all docs - namespace problem

Tags: mongodb

My app shows 13366 documents in a collection "ob-prerender".

I do a backup with `mongodump --archive=/root/mongodump.gz --gzip`

I get the backup back to local machine. It is a gz file of 500MB containing a dump of 3.2GB.

I restore it with `mongorestore --archive=[path]/mongodump.gz -h localhost --port 3001 --gzip --drop --nsFrom='prerender.*' --nsTo='meteor.*'`

First strange thing:

`finished restoring meteor.ob-prerender (7088 documents, 0 failures)
197939 document(s) restored successfully. 0 document(s) failed to restore.`

Why only 7088 docs when I know I have 13366 docs in the first place ?

Second strange thing the number of total documents actually restored and showned in Compass is 235 only.

What is happening ?

Scariest: I rerun the restore process with the same archive and now it says only 620 docs have been restored

`finished restoring meteor.ob-prerender (620 documents, 0 failures)
2020-05-24T13:08:41.398+0200    191471 document(s) restored successfully. 0 document(s) failed to restore.`

**EDIT** I think it is coming from the use of --nsFrom='prerender.*' as when I remove it the restore process is correct; Why is that ? Why all docs do not share the same namespace ?

Comment: You say that you want to import the collection `ob-prerender`, but are specifying `prerender.*` as the namespace. Shouldn't the namespace be `ob-prerender.*`? Do you have a collection named `prerender` in the original database, which you also dumped into the archive? I'm asking a lot, because I have never used namespaces in exports, but only specified `--collection` explicitly.

Comment: My goal is to restore the entire namespace of a backup that contains several databases. "prerender" is a namespace, "ob-prerender" is the name of a particular collection (not db or namespace) that I took as an example, but I had the same pb with the documents of other collections. I use namespaces as I have several DB in the same mongo instance. If I remove the nsFrom all databases are restored. I would like to avoid that.

Answer (score 1):

> My app shows 13366 documents in a collection "ob-prerender".

Okay, this is a collection name.

> I restore it with mongorestore --archive=[path]/mongodump.gz -h localhost --port 3001 --gzip --drop --nsFrom='prerender.*' --nsTo='meteor.*'

This is  a database name constraint, but you haven't provided any information in your question as to what databases you dumped, which collections they have and what documents are in those databases/collections.